# Symbolic Link seems to be Contradictory when dealing with '../'

Tags: filesystems, symlink

The contradiction here is how *symlink* deal with directory `../` in **2** ways:

- treat the current path as the **result printed by `pwd`**
- treat the current path as **absolute path**

I will discuss them with an example (pretty easy to understand).

---

Considering the following directory hierarchy:

```
/tmp/
  |__a/
  |  |__b/
  |
  |__sb=./a/b/ -> /tmp/a/b/  # the name `sb' means symbol b;
                             # `sb' is generated by:
                             # [/tmp/]$ ln -s ./a/b/ sb
```

1. _

   ```
   [/tmp/]$ cd sb  # `pwd' says we are now in /tmp/
                   # let's change to /tmp/a/b/

   [/tmp/sb/]$ cd ../  # Now we are in /tmp/a/b/
                       # But what is /tmp/a/b/'s parent dir?

   [/tmp/]$   # See?  We didn't come back to /tmp/a/ BUT /tmp/
   ```

   It means that the current *parent dir* is the second from the right **printed by `pwd`**.
2. Let's add a *symlink* into dir `/tmp/a/b/`:

   ```
   /tmp/
     |__a/
     |  |__b/
     |     |__sa=../ -> /tmp/a/  # [/tmp/a/b/]$ ln -s ../ sa
     |
     |__sb=./a/b/ -> /tmp/a/b/
   ```

   This time, we will come back to the actual *parent dir* of `/tmp/a/b/`:

   ```
   [/tmp/]$ cd sb  # change to /tmp/a/b/

   [/tmp/sb/]$ cd sa  # sa=../
                      # /tmp/sb/=/tmp/a/b/
                      #   ^    or     ^

   [/tmp/sb/sa/]$ ls --classify
   b/                 # ???
                      # We are now in /tmp/a/ because there is a b/ here!
   ```

   So Why this time it chooses to refer to the **absolute path** to determine the *parent dir*?

---

The contradiction arises when it comes to `../`, but I suspect the same thing happens when it comes to relative path.

All the above operations are tested on CentOS 7.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ````
> [/tmp/sb/]$ cd ../  # Now we are in /tmp/a/b/
>                     # But what is /tmp/a/b/'s parent dir?
>
> [/tmp/]$   # See? We didn't come back to /tmp/a/ BUT /tmp/ ```
> ````

That's because the shell remembers the path you used to get there, as a convenience.

It can be helpful in that you can link some long paths to short symlinks in your home directory, and then just go `cd thelink` and `cd ..` without ever needing to think of the long path again. Or in a multiuser system, the sysadmins can do it for you, and you need not ever even *know* the correct path.

But if you used `pwd -P` or `cd -P`, the shell would ignore that:

```
[/tmp]$ mkdir -p a/b; ln -s ./a/b sb
/tmp$ cd sb
[/tmp/sb]$ pwd -P
/tmp/a/b
[/tmp/sb]$ cd -P ..
/tmp/a$
```

---

> ```
> [/tmp/sb/]$ cd sa  # sa=../
>                    # /tmp/sb/=/tmp/a/b/
>                    #   ^    or     ^
>
> [/tmp/sb/sa/]$ ls --classify
> b/                 # ???
>                    # We are now in /tmp/a/ because there is a b/ here!
> ```

Here, the `...` in the symlink is resolved by the kernel, and it doesn't know anything about what the shell thinks. The shell still shows you the path you took (`sb`, then `sa`), and `cd ..` gets you back to `/tmp/sb`. Unless you use `-P`.

Similarly, if you run the external `pwd` utility instead, it'll show you the "physical" path, since it also can't know anything about which path you took.

```
[/tmp/sb/sa]$ pwd
/tmp/sb/sa
[/tmp/sb/sa]$ pwd -P
/tmp/a
[/tmp/sb/sa]$ /bin/pwd
/tmp/a
```

Incidentally, if you use `cd -P` to change the directory, it resolves the symlinks for the path shown by `pwd` and in the prompt:

```
[/tmp]$ cd -P sb/sa
[/tmp/a]$
```

Comment: so, all `$ pwd` (not `$ pwd -P`) does is just to ask shell the current dir remembered by shell?

Comment: @Shynur, pretty much yeah.